# Highstock Series Tooltip Data

Tags: highcharts

Could anyone tell us how to include the min. and max. values of the X-Axis in the tool tips.
For example if the chart is showing dates from April 2018 to April 2019 we would like to include this information within the tool tips for each series.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **tooltip.formatter** feature to customize the tooltip and attach that information in it.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5n38s1jx/

```
  tooltip: {
    formatter() {
      let point = this,
            xAxis = this.series.xAxis,
            output;

      output =  `<span style='font-size: 10px'>${point.key}</span><br/>
      <span style="color:${point.color}">●</span> ${point.series.name}: <b>${point.y}</b><br/>
      xAxis min: ${xAxis.min} && xAxis max: ${xAxis.max}`

      return output
    }   
  },
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

Comment: Wedzel Hi. Thanks for your response, but it does not work for me. I am using version 8 . Are you using the same version? Thanks

Comment: Yes, this is the newest Highcharts version. What do you see in the tooltip? On which browser are you testing it?

Comment: Wedzel. I just need to display the min & max date values from the x-Axis in a readable format i.e. not the milliseconds version.

Comment: Formatter callback can be fully customized. See: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yxfw16os/